# phpinfo() and loaded php.ini do not match

Tags: php, php-ini

It's happening something really weird, never happened to me before now. im working on a LEMP server (Ubuntu, PHP5-fpm, MySql, Nginx) and i modified `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`. Then i have decided to check my work through phpinfo(), but **none of my changes seem to be applied** .

phpinfo() says:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path : /etc/php5/fpm **(ok)**
- Loaded Configuration File : /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini **(ok)**

But the values displayed by phpinfo do not match with the loaded php.ini!!
For example `allow_url_fopen` is set to "Off" in php.ini, while both phpinfo() and ini_get("allow_url_fopen") return 1!! the same with "file_uploads", "expose_php" and so on..

any idea of what is happening? thank you

**EDIT**
Already tried:

- nginx restart
- php5-fpm restart
- server reboot
- the only php.ini file which can be loaded is the one i have modified because i do not have no others php installations (cli or "standard")

Comment: What about restarting the server?

Comment: Check for other php.ini's, the one for the Apache server is in a different place. On Ubuntu `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
`

Comment: *Sound familiar Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Totally Ralph!* Ah, the benefit of experience @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Yep yep yep!!* - Can't buy experience Sam - @JayBlanchard

Comment: try `service php-fpm reload` or `service php-fpm restart` after making changes to php.ini

Comment: *Save for some places in Nevada and Amsterdam Ralph* ;-) @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Funny the things you can get, while window-shopping, eh Sam?!* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: guys thank you all, but i have already tried both restart nginx and php and restart the server.. and still the same

Comment: Did you by chance append the settings to the end of the file? There are sections with `[…]` in the .ini file, which might keep your settings from properly being applied.